# LGA775 motherboard cpu support

Tags: cpu, motherboard

My motherboard says it doesn't support Pentium D 925, 935, 945. It supports 920, 930, 940, 950 but I inserted 925 and it worked. Could it cause any problems or incompatibility in some stuff? Why it doesn't support those CPUs?

This is my motherboard:  http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=589&MenuID=16&LanID=9

Comment: I see nothing on the specifications on your motherboard that says it does not support those CPUs you listed, just because they are not listed, does not mean they are not supported. *ECS isn't known for having the greatest documentation in the first place.*

Comment: @Ramhound click the cpu tab on that page, it lists "validated" cpu's, you are correct others may in fact work, they have just not been validated by ecs.

Comment: @Moab - I understand.  My point is, those CPUs are not explicitly, not support but infact are implicitly supported since it it is a 775 motherboard which supports the 920.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU tab you refer to in your link only says these are the processors that have been Validated (tested) by ECS and are guaranteed to be supported, this does not mean others will not work.

From the CPU page

> - means validated by ECS at time of writing. Changes to component or CPU may produce a different outcome. The result shown is for reference only and is subject to change w/o notification.